# PHP Error T_STRING

Tags: php, syntax-error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Community/register.php on line 84
```

I get that error, here is line 84 of my code.

```
   if ($firstname && $lastname && $username && $email && $password && $repassword){

        if ($password == $repassword){
                if (strstr($email, "@") && strstr($email, ".") && (strlen($email) >= 6)) {
                        require("scripts/connect.php");
                        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'); 
                        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query); 
                        if ($numrows == 0){ $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'"); 
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

Any ideas as to how I can fix this?

Comment: The error might be on lines before this line. Please show us the code preceding this line.

Comment: if ($firstname && $lastname && $username && $email && $password && $repassword){
  if ($password == $repassword){
   if (strstr($email, "@") && strstr($email, ".") && (strlen($email) >= 6)){
    
    require("scripts/connect.php");
    
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username');
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if ($numrows == 0){
     
     $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see by the code pasted in your (hard to read) comment that the problem is on a line several lines before the line posted in your question which is missing a close quote. The line that reads:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username');
```

should be:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
```

And BTW, you may want to do some research on [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection) as I believe your code may have some vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing `"` here:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
                                                                    ^
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it.  Never closed the string of the first query:

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username');
```

Notice missing close quotation.

I suggest using a syntax highlighting text editor.